# CSS absolute div inside relative parent for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to position a div inside a table. The parent has `position: relative` while my div las `position: absolute`. I usually develop in chrome and it works just fine there but when I open firefox my absolute div ignores it's parent and occupies the whole page.

Here's an example which works in chrome but not in firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/pdFSh/

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Comment: `<div>` inside any table tag will not pass in the W3 Validator, if you care about it.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Lol! I would just put that right now :)

Comment: @gustavohenke, <div> is completely valid in <td> in both HTML 4/XHTML 1 and HTML5, the content model of <td> allows any block elements in all these standards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to change the `display` value of `#absolute`'s parent:

```
table tr#body td { display: block; }
```

Comment: you are answer is fine but how its working can you explain....

Comment: Sure. By default, a table cell's `display` is `table-cell`. Firefox ([wrongly](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895)—thanks Ilya Streltsyn) treats table cells differently. Setting `display: block` instructs Firefox to no longer treat the `td` element as a table cell, but instead treats it as a block-level element. `display: inline-block` would work just as well.

Comment: setting parent to `display: block` solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 7):

It was [the known bug of Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895) *(fixed since Firefox 31)*. Before it was fixed, the common workarounds were nesting the div inside the table cell and setting position: relative to it, or changing the display of the cell itself to display:block (which converts the cell to a div-like block box nested in the anonymous table cell box). The second approach seemed to be applicable in this case because the height of the cell is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding the following to the `table tr#body td` CSS:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

You now will have to watch for margins and padding errors, however these can be avoided by changing the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) on the elements.

A further note, you should get in the habit of always placing a semi-colon, `;`, at the end of **every** line of CSS styling.

Edit: Adding `display: block` also works as posted by [Andre Dion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488102/1808539)

Comment: These properties are unnecessary. They work because `float: left` sets `display: block`. Simply setting `display: block` is adequate.